# Should I provide TLS connections in a service that is designed to run behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: encryption, networks, ssl

Does it make sense to implement TLS encryption for a service which will always be behind a reverse proxy?  The reverse proxy will be able to handle encryption to users directly.

```
  +-------------------------------+
  | +---------+     +---------+   |
  | | service |<--->| reverse |<--O---> Internet
  | |         |     |  proxy  |   |
  | +---------+     +---------+   |
  +-------------------------------+
```

These are the arguments I could think of, but I cannot quite decide which side makes weighs more:

### Cons

- Unnecessary complexity in the code which might lead to problems in the future.
- Would need to use self-signed certificates anyway, so no CA based authentication.
- No actual security gain: if the machine is compromised, transport encryption is futile anyway.

### Pros

- An additional layer of security in case the internal network is compromised.  (Not relevant if service and proxy are on the same physical machine?)
- Service can not accidentally be exposed unencrypted.

Comment: ***which will always be behind a reverse proxy*** until it won't be.

Answer (score 2):

At some point you will have to defend your choice in a security audit.

In the case of traffic crossing the network (even an internal network) there will be some scenario where having encryption would at a minimum "make things harder" for an attacker. Bluntly, its more work trying to defend a decision not to encrypt than it is to add certificates to the servers - especially if you just assume you need to encrypt all traffic from the beginning.

In the case of running both the app server and the proxy on the same machine - where the app server only exposes its ports on the loopback/localhost interface. I am not aware of any attack that encryption would help prevent - primarily because in order to sniff traffic on the loopback interface, an attacker would need escalated privileges on the machine anyway.